# Windows AlphaBlend with buffer usage

Tags: c, winapi, transparency, chromium-embedded, alphablending

I would like to draw a buffer (with alpha information!) within a given window. The drawing is done outside of WM_PAINT (it is done in CefRenderHandler::OnPaint method called from Chromium-Embedded-Framework).

The problem, that I have are:

- old content of the window is not cleared (if buffer is changed, I get old content drawn and new content drawn).
- the alpha channel is wrongly interpreted - I think, that even though the pixel has the alpha information, it is painted as it would not have the alpha information

This is what I have so far:

OnPaint(...):

```
HDC screen_dc = GetDC(windowHandle);
RECT rcWin;
GetClientRect(windowHandle, &rcWin);

BITMAPINFO info;
ZeroMemory(&info, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
info.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
info.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = width*height * 4;
info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

void *buf;
HBITMAP hDib = CreateDIBSection(screen_dc, &info, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (void **)&buf, 0, 0);
memcpy(buf, buffer, width * height * 4); //buffer contains bitmap to draw
HDC hDibDC = CreateCompatibleDC(screen_dc);
HGDIOBJ hOldObj = SelectObject(hDibDC, hDib);
BLENDFUNCTION blendFunction_;
blendFunction.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
blendFunction.BlendFlags = 0;
blendFunction.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
blendFunction.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
AlphaBlend(screen_dc, 0, 0, width, height, hDibDC, 0, 0, width, height, blendFunction);

SelectObject(hDibDC, hOldObj);
ReleaseDC(windowHandle, screen_dc);
DeleteObject(hDib);
DeleteDC(hDibDC);
```

Window creation:

```
WNDCLASSEX wcex = {0};
wcex.cbSize = sizeof(wcex);
wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wcex.lpfnWndProc = BrowserWindowWndProc;
wcex.hInstance = hinstance;
wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wcex.hbrBackground = WHITE_BRUSH;
wcex.lpszClassName = BROWSER_WINDOW_CLASS;
wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

DWORD exStyle{0};
exStyle |= WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;
exStyle |= WS_EX_LAYERED;

DWORD style {0};
style |= WS_SYSMENU;
style |= WS_VISIBLE;

HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
    exStyle,
    BROWSER_WINDOW_CLASS, 
    BROWSER_WINDOW_CLASS,
    style,
    100,
    100,
    300,
    300,
    nullptr,
    nullptr, 
    hinstance,
    nullptr
);
...
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(255, 255, 255), 255, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

Could you help me with these problems?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: in OnPaint you should use the hdc taken from BeginPaint function instead of using GetDC. This might solve the problem with the background contents. As for the wrong alpha values, you might need to premultiply the alpha values in the bitmap as shown here: http://www.fengyuan.com/article/alphablend.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to use both `AlphaBlend` and layered windows. Use layered windows only:

```
void OnPaint(HDC hdc, int width, int height, HBITMAP hbitmap)
{
    HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    auto oldbmp = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);

    BITMAP bm;
    GetObject(hbitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
    DeleteDC(memdc);
}
```

Where `hbitmap` is a handle to the bitmap created earlier. The white areas of the bitmap should appear as transparent when using `SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, RGB(255,255,255), 255, LWA_COLORKEY);`

Or use `LWA_COLORKEY | LWA_ALPHA` to adjust both transparency and alpha level.

Assuming `OnPaint` is a response to `WM_PAINT`, use `BeginPaint/EndPaint` instead of `GetDC/ReleaseDC`

Note that `WHITE_BRUSH` is zero, so `wcex.hbrBackground = WHITE_BRUSH;` sets the background brush to zero. Assign a brush handle instead.

Alternatively you can use `TransparentBlt` in the same window:

```
HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
auto oldbmp = SelectObject(memdc, hbitmap);

BITMAP bm;
GetObject(hbitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);
TransparentBlt(hdc, 0, 0, width, height, 
    memdc, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, RGB(255, 255, 255));

SelectObject(memdc, oldbmp);
DeleteDC(memdc);
```

Comment: Yes, it works. The only thing, that is kind of not working is semi-transparent pixels (that are within the hbitmap). But I can leave with that now.
I have used TransparentBlt. I do not use LWA_ALPHA, as it does transparency to all the pixels (I do not want that).
I am painting that outside of WM_PAINT, so I need to use GetDC/ReleaseDC

Comment: Is this from a *.png file? Give more information in the question about the image, if possible upload a sample (the default upload would convert the *.bmp to *.png)

Comment: No, it is not a static image, I have mentioned, that buffer comes from Chromium-Embedded-Framework. So in other words, it is a buffer generated by chromium from html.

Comment: If bitmap image has premultiplied alpha then your method should work fine. Try doing the same thing but not in a layered window. I don't think it does have premultiplied alpha. You can post some images of what it looks like and what you think it should look like, or leave it as is... If you own the window then you can paint in `WM_PAINT`, and send `InvalidateRect` message to force repaint.

Comment: Not using layered window breaks it - the transparency does not work. But, maybe it is a problem of CEF/chromium - that generates bitmap with such background. 
Note: I do not use WM_PAINT nor WM_ERASEBKGND.
Anyway, Thanks for all the help